# TV cords showing

Tags: cleaning, home

Does any one of you geniuses out there have a good life hack on hiding TV cords from a TV that is mounted on the wall? Preferably a decorative hack. I want them completely hidden.

Comment: Hi Kayla, can you tell us a bit more about your setup? E.g. where are the cables going and is there already anything else on the wall with the tv (cupboards etc.)?

Comment: A photo of the TV and wall would give us a better idea of where the cords are and how to hide them!

Answer (score 2):

Transform them into art. See below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't do this! The tight radius on all those corners damages the cables.

Comment: The radius depends on the cables, of course. Shaping an HDMI cable as tight as if you would shape a mouse cord is definitely a bad idea. If the HDMI cord is long enough, some kind of infinity sign is already enough, and the radius needs not be tight.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, you have 3 options...

1. Use a PVC cable cover strip

[image]

[image]

2. Use a rubber/ plastic cable protection

[image]

3. Last but not least, if you don't want ANY cables, have a wall power socket installed behind your TV and get your HDMI/ audio cables installed in your walls.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is a tall plant or indoor tree (even a fake one). I assume the cords just hang down from the wall-mounted TV, so you could place the plant in front of them.

[image]

One advantage of a fake plant is that you can get one that's exactly the right height, and you won't have to deal with it growing taller.